# Java - Put XML Source into another one

Tags: java, xml, put

---

Hi,

I need to put this xml into another one.
I add  tag as root. Can anyone help me please?

Please, see examples:

### Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TBCOMPROBANTE>
       <cuitEmpresa>N11</cuitEmpresa>
       <numeroComprobante>N9</numeroComprobante>
       <nombreArchivo>A41</nombreArchivo>
       <codigoIntegridad>A50</codigoIntegridad>
       <validacionesRemitos class="list">
          <remito>
             <numeroUnico>A16</numeroUnico>
             <procesado>A2</procesado>
          </remito>
          <remito>
             <numeroUnico>A16</numeroUnico>
             <procesado>A2</procesado>
             <errores class="list">
                <error>
                   <codigo>N2</codigo>
                   <descripcion>A150</descripcion>
                </error>
             </errores>
          </remito>
       </validacionesRemitos>
    </TBCOMPROBANTE>
```

### Target (see new Arba tag a root)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Arba>
   <TBCOMPROBANTE>
      <cuitEmpresa>N11</cuitEmpresa>
      <numeroComprobante>N9</numeroComprobante>
      <nombreArchivo>A41</nombreArchivo>
      <codigoIntegridad>A50</codigoIntegridad>
      <validacionesRemitos class="list">
         <remito>
            <numeroUnico>A16</numeroUnico>
            <procesado>A2</procesado>
         </remito>
         <remito>
            <numeroUnico>A16</numeroUnico>
            <procesado>A2</procesado>
            <errores class="list">
               <error>
                  <codigo>N2</codigo>
                  <descripcion>A150</descripcion>
               </error>
            </errores>
         </remito>
      </validacionesRemitos>
   </TBCOMPROBANTE>
</Arba>
```

Cerbero ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Start by reading up on the APIs available in Java for manipulating XML documents. I'd suggest either DOM or SAX -- DOM might be easier  for a beginner. The JAXP APIs, which ship with Java, provide XML parsers (for input) and serializers (for output) for either of those options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following steps:

1. Parse the input file using the Java DOM Parser
2. Find the node of interest
3. Create a new document with the new node
4. Copy the node from the first document and add it as a child of the new node
5. Finally, write out the new document to a file

Here is my example code

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XMLWrapper {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final File inputFile = new File(
                "/Users/richard/Documents/workspace/so/input.xml");
        final File outputFile = new File(
                "/Users/richard/Documents/workspace/so/output.xml");

        // Read in the file using the DOM parser
        final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        final Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputFile);

        // Find the TBCOMPROBANTE node
        final NodeList childNodes = document
                .getElementsByTagName("TBCOMPROBANTE");
        final Node chosenNode = childNodes.item(0);

        // Create a new document and add the extra node
        final Document newDocument = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        final Element createElement = newDocument.createElement("Arba");
        newDocument.appendChild(createElement);

        // Import the node we found and append it to the new element
        final Node importNode = newDocument.importNode(chosenNode, true);
        createElement.appendChild(importNode);
        newDocument.normalize();

        // Use a Transformer to write the xml to outputFile
        final TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        final Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        final DOMSource source = new DOMSource(newDocument);
        final StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputFile);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    }
}
```